# how to query mongoDB to get the documents that have the _id value that matches one _id value in an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array in Nodejs that contains document _id values of mongoDB documents  that needs to be retrieved. So I need to query mongoDB such a way that it should return the documents that have the _id value that matches at least 1 _id value in the array that I want to pass in to query. The length of the array is unknown. I looked at the documentation but couldn't see something related.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
db.col.find({ _id: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } })
```

Comment: But in documentation it says that $in oparator returns boolean? [here]https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

Comment: @AkilDemir there are two $in operators and you've linked the other one (for aggregation). The one I'm referring to is for queries

Comment: oh got it. Thanks